# SetTimeout inside SetInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node js as server. To avoid instant disconnecting of users on page refresh and give buffer time for reloading I'm using SetTimeout inside SetInterval as followed. Users are added to the array "remove" on Disconnect event. If the Users dont return then they are eventually removed. I'm doing this with the help of **Cookies**

```
var remove=[];
socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
remove.push(socket.id);
});


setInterval(myTimer, 120000);
function myTimer()
{
  var removed = remove;
  remove=[];
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    for(i=0; i < removed.length; i++)
    {
      connection.query("DELETE FROM users WHERE socketid='"+removed[i]+"'");
      console.log(removed[i]+" is disconnected");
    }
  }, 60000);
}
```

The code is working totally fine.
But is it ok to have this kind of loop on server side? Will they ever overlap due to delaying of execution? Will it be executed on time?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0;i<=10;i++) {
   (function(ind) {
      setTimeout(function(){console.log(ind);}, 1000 + (3000 * ind));
   })(i);
}
```

It is fine to use loops at server side, but you need to take care of them by using closures, like in the above example.
Closures will help them executing the code in the correct context, and will avoid overlap.